# Names for DLLImport when moving C# from Unity script to Mono DLL

Tags: mono, unity-game-engine

I have a working Unity C# script which calls into a native iOS static library. I would like to move the C# code from the Unity script attached to a scene object and into a new Mono DLL. I'll then rewrite the Unity C# script to call the Mono DLL. I'm unsure how to name the DLL representing the imported native iOS static library (the .a file)

In the C# script I have this external declaration:

```
[DllImport("__Internal")]
private static extern int square(int x);
```

What should the DLL name be when I copy those lines over to the Mono DLL?

Comment: I am confused.  On the one hand you say you want to move the script code to a native iOS static library and on the other you say you want to move it to a Mono DLL.  If the former, then you have the right syntax and if the latter you don't need `DllImport` at all.

Comment: I don't think I say I want to move the script code to a native iOS static library? Let me check my wording. I want to move the script code to a Mono DLL, and it is code that *calls* a native iOS static library. The sysntax may be correct, but is the name "__Internal"?

Comment: I might have mis-read.  Anyhow you don't need to decorate with `DllImport` in that case.

Comment: Are you sure - to call from a Mono C# DLL into a native iOS static library I do not need a DllImport? How do I write the call?

Comment: Ah perhaps I mis-read again.  The long-and-short of it is it should not change regardless of whether the code is in a script attached to a GameObject or within a Mono (C#) DLL.  Just move the code and it should work I believe.

Comment: Now I have all the build issues sorted out I've found that you are completely correct, in my Mono DLL I can continue to refer to "__Internal" as the name for the DLL created by Unity from the native iOS static library .a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to turn @Droppy's comments into an answer, the C# I have in the Unity script:

```
[DllImport("__Internal")]
private static extern int square(int x);
```

works without change as part of a Mono DLL imported as an asset into a Unity project. I did not need to search for a more specific name than the Unity magic "__Internal".

(N.B. Example code is available [here](https://github.com/dumbledad/GreenBox/tree/b4f22f2323036d5a8bc185999b6224d04ca519e8).)